# Export datatable from MySQL to Text file without the delimiter

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to export data from the datatable. The datas successfully exported but the thing is that I can't remove the delimiter of fields. This is what my code looks like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM datatable 
INTO OUTFILE 'D:/try.txt' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' 
ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

This is the list of columns the datatable has:

[image: datatable columns]

I already did remove the fields terminated by but the datas still delimited by tabs. What should I do? Help me please. Thankyou!

Comment: Why would you want to remove the delimiter?

Comment: company standards we have our own delimiter which the fields in the table has max length and position

Comment: Indicate the type of data of the columns to export. See [13.2.7 LOAD DATA Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html): `If the FIELDS TERMINATED BY and FIELDS ENCLOSED BY values are both empty (''), a fixed-row (nondelimited) format is used. With fixed-row format, no delimiters are used between fields (but you can still have a line terminator). Instead, column values are read and written using a field width wide enough to hold all values in the field.`, but this has some limitations, for example, columns of data type TEXT are not allowed.

Comment: Can't understand it clearly can you state an example?

Comment: Can you add to your question the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE datatable;` and indicate the columns to export?.

Comment: Done editing. Your query returns an error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SHOW TABLE datatable' at line 1"

Comment: @JamilleAñonuevo - SHOW **CREATE** TABLE ... . And, no, that "list of columns in not sufficient."

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but you could run `sed` from the bash on your file, after it has been exported:

```
sed 's/\t//g' D:/try.txt > D:/try-no-tabs.txt
```

The above is a Linux option.  Here is a Windows batch script which should do the same:

```
@set @a=0  /*
@cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < D:/try.txt > D:/try-no-tabs.txt
@move /Y D:/try-no-tabs.txt D:/try.txt
@goto :EOF */
WScript.Stdout.Write( WScript.StdIn.ReadAll().replace(/\t/g,""));
```

Save this as a `.bat` file and then run it.

Comment: No idea about bash can you please introduce me with that?

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am running windows